# xpages partial - full search

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I saw a great tutorial from IBM explaining creating a search modulo into a view panel.

The code from the viewpanel ( `search` property ) I adjusted:

```
 "(Field txt_autor = \"" + sessionScope.searchAutor + "\")";
    }
```

Is there any chance I can modify the code so that it offers the search results for the partial string matches also, for example: if `Autor = Smith` and in the string `searchAutor = Smit` currently I get 0 documents / 0 results. Something like `CONTAINS` will be useful, if it's possible.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Instead of if (sessionScope.searchAutor != null & sessionScope.searchAutor != "") {, use just if (sessionScope.searchAutor) { - it is "JavaScript"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a star "*" in front and at the end of every search string like `"*Smit*"`.

Your code would look like this then

```
tmpArray[cTerms++]= "(Field txt_titlu = \"*" + sessionScope.searchTitle + "*\")";
```