# xpages search not working for new doc. created

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I created a partial search modulo with a little help: [xpages partial - full search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486456/xpages-partial-full-search)

What I noticed is that when I created a new document and saving it, I can not search it immediately using this code considering the fact that I'm using session variables....

Also, my xpages application runs on web using Session Based Authentification.

Just to be clear: There are 5 docs. already saved in my App, the search is working OK. I created a new doc & save it. I try to search this last document and it won't work. Sometimes it works, after I logout the app. and login again, but sometimes it doesn't...

Is there any-other solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full text index is not a real time operation. On creation of a document the update of the FTIndex is queued and availability of the result depends on total server load.

If you are refering to search in a view (not ftsearch), check your view index that it is set to instant update and if really needed add a view refresh into the post save event

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm using a ftsearch, helped by this tutorial: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesViewControlAddFullTextSearch.htm ( I made only some minor modifications ). So, in this case my searching depends on the total server load? A view refresh on the post save event can help me? ( I'm not sure I understand your answer  - my english is not perfect - Should I use the view refresh only for a search in a view, and not for ftsearch ? )

Comment: Ftsearch runs against the FTIndex. A view refresh has no influence on it. A view refresh is a costly operation. Use only when needed. Check your application: do you depend on ftsearch too much? How about a view "newly created"